# python nltk calculations

Tags: python, nlp

i string data or sentences

> دنیا کے کسی بھی انسان کی

what i need to do here is split my words like

> دنیا کے
>
> کے کسی
>
> کسی بھی
>
> بھی انسان
>
> انسان کی

and so on. i have to do this without using nltk.

i have tried one but it is giving me unicode data but i want it in proper urdu.

Code:

```
import codecs
import re
import sys
import io
import itertools
fil1 = codecs.open(".txt","r+", encoding="utf-8")
fil3 = codecs.open(".txt","w",encoding="utf-8")
ans=[]
for line in fil1:
    arr = line.split()
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i < len(arr)-1:
            ans.append([[arr[i]], [arr[i+1]]])
    print ans
```

Output of this code:

> [[u'\u062f\u0646\u06cc\u0627'], [u'\u06a9\u06d2']],
>   [[u'\u06a9\u06d2'], [u'\u06a9\u0633\u06cc']],
>   [[u'\u06a9\u0633\u06cc'], [u'\u0628\u06be\u06cc']],
>   [[u'\u0628\u06be\u06cc'], [u'\u0627\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0646']],
>   [[u'\u0627\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0646'], [u'\u06a9\u06cc']],
>   [[u'\u06a9\u06cc'], [u'\u0633\u0628']]

How to split my data like this without using nltk or any library?

Comment: Can you please add the code that you are running? Also, change the output to text, rather than an image.

Comment: ok done i have added code and output

Comment: The above seems to be an encoding issue, try to use `utf-8`, try to write them to a file and see how they look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fix [Here](https://repl.it/NqXU/0)

Just use the below logic, and apply it, if you are writing to a file, you should make sure you configure the encoding correctly.

```
myString = "دنیا کے کسی بھی انسان کی"

import codecs
import re
import sys
import io
import itertools

ans=[]

ans=[]
arr = myString.split(" ")
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i < len(arr)-1:
       print arr[i] + " " + arr[i+1]
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

The reason it looks like that is because the strings are stored as unicode and are printed like that in lists, dicts etc. If you want to the program to output the correct characters, you can print the list, like so:

```
for word1, word2 in ans:
    print word1[0], word2[0]
```

Writing to a file will also give the correct characters.